# My Floyd Rose won't stay in tune

Tags: guitar, tuning

I'm pretty new to Floyd Rose. My Floyd Rose wont stay in tune. My strings will go sharp after 15 minutes after tuning, the bridge is a bit higher from the body but the string action is really low as well. Please help if there's any way to fix that.

Comment: Do you have a locking nut and is it properly locked?

Comment: Are the strings new - although they tend to go flat initially.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Yeah,Tim no the strings are neither new neither old

Comment: @Tim no the strings are neither new neither old

Comment: Could you be rubbing the fine tuning knobs with your hand while you play? Could you post a video of it being in tune and then playing and then it's sharp?

Comment: @ToddWilcox the thing i tuned it then saw after a minute of playing with bends and fast strumming and stuff it was out of tune then i tighten the locking nuts a little bit more, i tuned it but after a little bit of playing they went sharp.Plus i found another issue wiht my high e,i cant bend it on the higher threats and when i do dive bombs it doesnt go as slack as the other strings

Comment: Alright so i tune the guitar play after 1-2 minutes all the strings go flat and the low e never stays tuned,then after a dive bomb almost alll the strings go perfectly in tune

Answer (score 6):

When tuning a Floyd Rose, it is best to have the fine tuners about half way through their range, then tune all the strings using the machine heads.

Then give the term bar a good shake, both sharp and flat, and then tune using the machine heads. And then properly tighten your locking nut. At this point it is likely to be slightly out of tune again, so another bit of whammy bar and then tuning using the fine tuners should be enough.

When I do that I can expect it to stay in tune for a week or more if I don't play it, or most of a gig if I'm really hammering on the bar.

From your comments I can only think the lock nut may not be tightened enough.

Additionally, your trem should sit parallel with the guitar surface, so if it isn't, tighten or loosen your springs by turning the screws in the back of the guitar that hold the spring bar. We have various other posts on this here.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a Floyd Rose user personnaly. So this answer is kind of a "link to someone who knows better" type of thing, hoping that it will help you.

Phillip McKnight has done a great series of videos about Floyd Rose:

- [How to live with a Floyd Rose when you hate it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDsO-HfLuhQ)
- [How Floy Rose bridges work](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iloVCP9yl7I)
- [How to restring a Floyd Rose quick and easy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIdlezH32hw)

Answer (score 1):

they might be *binding* at the saddles. What worked for me was 1) moving the strings off the saddle (you could wedge something under the bridge to get access with the strings then going all floppy 2) rubbing a soft graphite pencil onto the saddle where the string meets so that some graphite is deposited there. 3) returning the strings to pitch